# Prevent render on the Second Component when state changes for the first

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have written a simple React POC where I have a Main component and two child components. The entire state of the application is maintained in the Main component. when the state changes, the child components are re-rendered when the new state is passed as props.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
class Comp1 extends React.Component<IProps1, any> {
  render() {
    console.log('going to render Component1')
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input type='text' value={this.props.curtext} onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={(e) => this.props.onSave(this.props.curtext)}>save</button>
      </React.Fragment> 
    )
  }
}
class Comp2 extends React.Component<IProps2, any> {
  render() {
    console.log('going to render Component2')
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul>
          {this.props.items.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
class Main extends React.Component<any, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currtext: "",
      items: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(text: string) {
    this.setState({currtext: text})
  }
  onSave(text: string) {
    var copy = this.state.items;
    copy.push(text)
    this.setState({currtext: "", items: copy})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Comp1 handleChange={this.handleChange} curtext={this.state.currtext} onSave={this.onSave} />
        <Comp2 items= {this.state.items} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"))

interface IState {
  currtext: string
  items: Array<string>
}
interface IProps1 {
  handleChange: (text: string) => void,
  curtext: string,
  onSave: (text: string) => void
}

interface IProps2 {
  items: Array<string>
}
```

The only problem with the app is that when the property "currtext" of the state changes, Component2 is still re-rendered.

what I expected was that curtext changes, then Component1 is rendered and when the items is changed then Component2 re-renders.

but right now I see Component2 being re-rendered on every keystroke in the input text box which changes only the part of the state with which Component2 is not concerned.

Edit:: Based on suggestion below I changed the code of component 2 to

```
class Comp2 extends React.Component<IProps2, any> {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: IProps2, nextState: any) {
    console.log(nextProps.items);
    console.log(this.props.items);
    if (nextProps.items.toString() === this.props.items.toString()) {
      return false 
    } else { 
      return true
    }
  }
  render() {
    console.log('going to render Component2')
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul>
          {this.props.items.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Now if I enter something in text box and click save. I see that the nextProps.items and this.props.items are always same and therefore my component2 doesn't render at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Comp2 re-renders is because when the parent state changes everything inside of the parents render method will be re-rendered.

```
 class Comp2 extends React.Component<IProps2, any> {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if(nextProps.currtext) return false;
  return true;
  }
  render() {
    console.log('going to render Component2')
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul>
          {this.props.items.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Try adding the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle hook.

Pass currtext into Comp2 as a prop. If currtext contains a letter the Comp2 will not update. Once you submit and currtext becomes "" empty it will update.

`<Comp2 items= {this.state.items} currtext={this.state.currtext} />`

Also do not mutate state directly.

```
  onSave(text: string) {
    var copy = this.state.items.slice();
    copy.push(text)
    this.setState({currtext: "", items: copy})
  }
```

Comment: I updated my question above. for me the nextProps.items is always equal to this.props.items.

Comment: Well when onSave is called nextProps.items will not be equal to this.Props.items because nextProps.items will have a new string in it. But try this implementation

Comment: yeah the problem was that I was not doing the slice. slice fixed it. thanks!